# What is LValues and RValues in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, lvalue, rvalue

There are two kinds of expressions in Objective-C

**1. RValue**

```
 The term rvalue refers to a data value that is stored at some address in memory
```

**2. LValue**

`Expressions that refer to a memory location is called "lvalue" expression. An lvalue may appear as` `either the left-hand or right-hand side of an assignment`

I didn't get it . can someone explain it to me?

Comment: l for left and r for right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RValue is a value that is evaluated but does not have a designated memory address to be stored until assigned to such a memory location. For example :

`5 * 2` is an expression evaluated to the number `10`. This evaluated expression is still not assigned to a memory address (only a temporary one used for the calculation but you cannot directly refer to it) and will be lost if not stored. And this is the role of the LValue to provide a memory location to store the evaluated expression :

```
int x;
x = 5 * 2;
```

Here `x` refers to a certain memory address and the calculated number (10) can now be stored where `x` refers to (i.e. in the memory space assigned to `x`) via the assignment operator. So in the example above x is the LValue and the expression `5 * 2` is the RValue

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, `lvalue` are values that can be assigned to. In C and Objective-C, those are usually variables and pointer dereferences. `rvalue`s are results of expressions that can't be assigned to.

Some examples:

```
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
int *ptr = &i;

// "i" is a lvalue, "1" is a rvalue
i = 1;
// "*ptr" is a lvalue, "j + 1" is a rvalue
*ptr = j + 1;
// lvalues can be used on both sides of assignment
i = j;

// invalid, since "j + 1" is not a rvalue
(j + 1) = 2
```

See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_(computer_science)) and [this article here](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/Lvalues%20and%20Rvalues.htm) for more details.